# Generic Type Error TS2322: Type '{ id: null; }' is not assignable to type 'T'

Tags: typescript

I am getting a TS type checking error on the code below.

```js
interface Resource {
  id: string;
}

interface ResourceState<T> {
  data: T;
  hash: string;
}

abstract class ResourceComponent<R extends Resource> {
  protected state: ResourceState<R> = {
    data: { // Type checking KO
      id: ''
    },
    hash: ''
  };
}

// Doesn't suit my use case
// abstract class ResourceComponent<Resource> {
//   protected state: ResourceState<Resource> = {
//     data: {
//       id: null
//     },
//     hash: ''
//   };
// }

interface Model extends Resource {
  name: string;
}

class ModelComponent extends ResourceComponent<Model> {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state.data.name = 'ModelComponent'; // Type checking OK
    this.state.data.age = 20; // Type checking OK
    console.log(this.state.data);
  }
}

const component = new ModelComponent();
```

On line 12 precisely, I am getting error TS2322: Type '{ id: null; }' is not assignable to type 'R'. Shouldn't TypeScript understand that since 'R extends Resource', data could be initialised with a value that has Resource Type's shape.

On lines 36, 37, TS does type checking correctly.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rthmqv

Comment: Do you have `--structNullChecks` enabled?  If you do (and it's recommended) then `null` isn't a string.

Comment: This is not related to null. I've modified the snippet for clarity and added a stackblitz. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you need to tell your data object that what you are assigning to it is actually R

```
abstract class ResourceComponent<R extends Resource> {
  protected state: ResourceState<R> = {
    data : { // Type checking KO
      id: "null"
    } as R,
    hash: ''
  };
}
```

Comment: That works. But I would like TypeScript to infer it.